# Doesn't call fragment from notification bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, notifications

I am calling fragment class from notification bar click event. But when i click on that notification bar i can't open that fragment class which i have called for that i have checked it with one static boolean variable. still it is not working.

***Code for Notification:***

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

        int icon = R.drawable.kutch_smallpng;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = null;
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainMenuActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity

        if (notificationIntent != null) {
            notificationIntent.setAction("CurrentOffersFragment" + requestID);

        }

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestID,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        // notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        // notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                getApplicationContext()).setWhen(when).setContentText(message)
                .setContentTitle(title).setSmallIcon(icon).setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
                .setContentIntent(intent);
        Uri defaultRingtoneUri = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultRingtoneUri);
        notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        notificationManager.notify((int) when, notification);

        Log.v("My Message is", message);
        notificationClicked = true;

    }
```

Now in `MainMenuActivity's onCreate()` method calling like this.

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();

        if (intent != null) {

            Log.e("Is Clicked", "true");

            try {
                if (notificationClicked == true
                        && intent.getAction().equals("CurrentOffersFragment")) {
                    Fragment fragment = new CurrentOffersFragment();

                    // txtMainTitlebar.setText("Current Offers");
                    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    ft.add(R.id.container, fragment);
                    fragmentStack.push(fragment);
                    ft.commit();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception

            }

            // }

        }
```

But here it did not fulfill condition of `notificationClicked == true
                            && intent.getAction().equals("CurrentOffersFragment")`.

So please help for this. It will be appropriate.

Comment: I think your problem is `notificationClicked`, try debug your application and find what is the value of that. I think you need save `notificationClicked` on application property

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I know the problem is there thats y it didn't called. But i have just change the boolean value after click on notification. and in activity i have checked with that boolean variable.

Comment: where you define `notificationClicked`? in `MainMenuActivity`? after notification clicked new Activity started so `notificationClicked` has default value (false )

Comment: @shayanpourvatan No it is in GCMIntentService class.

Comment: but you changed local `notificationClicked` in `generateNotification` and check local `notificationClicked` in `MainMenuActivity`. as this file is separated how you want check value?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan first GCM push notification generated in main activity and in that activity i have also checked with boolean variable that if it is true then fragment open which value will be set in notification coding with true.

Comment: In your notification method you can use intent.putExtra("key","value"); method to passing data.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA Can you help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029980/deploy-android-app-through-google-play-private-channel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got answer. What i have changed

Make static boolean variable in my MainMenuActivity

```
public static boolean notificationClicked = false;
```

and after that make it true in notification class

```
notificationClicked = true;
```

and check in MainMenuActivity with

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();

        if (intent != null) {

            try {
                if (notificationClicked == true) {
                    Fragment fragment = new CurrentOffersFragment();

                    txtMainTitlebar.setText("Current Offers");
                    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    ft.add(R.id.container, fragment);
                    fragmentStack.push(fragment);
                    ft.commit();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception

            }

            // }

             }
```

The problem was here

```
 if (notificationIntent != null) {
        notificationIntent.setAction("CurrentOffersFragment" + requestID);

  }
```

So i have just removed that one. Working like charm.