# Deploy android app through google play private channel

Tags: android, deployment, google-play

Hi i am trying to upload my Android app in the private channel of the Google Play store, this will be first app for our organization. We didn't upload any apps yet but we are trying to upload our first app in private Channel. I didn't find how to get start with Google play private channel. I go through this [distribute android apps in your organization](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en.) but am a bit confuse about what the first step is. Can anybody tell me how to get started?

My first step is through this screen. So where is "Click More controls > Other Google Services, click filter to open the filter pane, and deselect the Show top featured services checkbox"..[image]

Comment: I am agree with your edit , but what is step for my question ? will please close this thread for me. Thanks for edit suggestion.

Comment: I want to close after getting perfect answer. If you want then i don't do that. Do you have any idea about this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's too late, but I just did it for the first time now, and I can guide you :)
I aggree with you : Google support is a bit confusing.

First of all, from the main dashboard, go to **Apps**, then **Additional Google services**. Then, at the top right of the screen, click the second button (a kind of filter icon), between "+" and "?", and uncheck in the left panel that appears "Show top featured services".

Then, on the same screen, scroll and make sure *Google Play Developer Console* and *Google Play for work* are activated.

Once done, go back to the main dashboard, and then go to **Device Management**. On the next screen click *Mobile* on the left panel.

There, click **Device management settings** and check *Allow users to access Google Play Private Channel* if you want your users are just able to download app, or the second checkbox *(**update** Goole Play Private Channel)* if you want they can upload custom apps too.

You can set this property for your whole domain, or for each "organizationnal unit", as Google says.

Then, you have to create an Android dev account with one of your Google Apps account. I mean : if you had a personnal dev account (with a gmail address, or anything else, you won't be able to be a dev in your organization), so beware !

The publication process will be the same, **except one thing** : in the "pricing/availability" menu in the Dev console, you will have to check a tiny checkbox just after the amazing list of countries, to warn Google you want this app to be just visible for users of your GApp domain.

An other pretty cool feature that may be relevant in this usecase is Android For Work, coupled with Google Play For Work. I can help you too about it, but it's another subject :)

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry to discover your post so late, I guess you find a solution by yourself ;-)
But I hope it may help people that will find out this post in future :)

Comment: Too bad I didn't see this post before I rushed to pay the $25 distribution fee with a personnal dev account and become a waste, because I have to delivery my app thru private channel and private channel is only available for organization for business.

Comment: If we deployed our app for example.com and our employees have email accounts person1@example.com. Now this person1@example.com is non-goggle account. With this email id, will they be able to download the app in their mobile from play store?

Comment: If the domain example.com is a Google Apps account, **and** if the person1@example.com is a registered Google Apps user in the Google Apps admin dashboard of the example.com domain, it will work.
If not, it won't.

Answer (score 0):

Google has provided step by step instructions of doing this. We can create users in the private domain and assign different privileges to the users, based on which, they can just download the app or upload apps to the private channel. The following link gives detailed information on this.
[enter link description here][1]
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for your response , i already go through this link but i am not able to find this step - "Click More controls > Other Google Services, click filter to open the filter pane, and deselect the Show top featured services checkbox"

Comment: @thasneem.. DO u have any idea how we do that?

Comment: 2. In the classic Admin console, click Users > Services.
In the new Admin console, click Other Google Services. If this is not available on the dashboard, you can find it under More Controls section. Turn off the filter if this is not visible under Services.

Comment: I update my question will you please , take look of it.?

Comment: Can you put a screen shot of your logged in Google Admin Console Page?

Comment: I have one doubt that is may be at first to do this step "Creating an account on the Google Developer Console for application publishing." then after that i am able get " Click More controls > Other Google Services, click filter to open the filter pane, and deselect the Show top featured services checkbox "in your suggested link. Is i am right or wrong? Because still i didn't pay $25 . Is it will come for me after payment.?

Comment: I did this sometime back. so dont remember exactly the order in which I did this. I remember when I was not able to find this option, I had to uncheck something in the filter available on top right. Can you try this?